# MapViewOfFile offset - how to use it

Tags: c, client-server, offset, file-mapping

Developing a game ("jogo" in PT),
 the server can host up to 5 simultaneous games,
 which the client will access via mapped memory.

So here's what I have:

Server:

```
#define MAX_JOGOS 5
typedef struct{
...
} sJogo;

typedef struct{
sJogo * pS;
} sGlobals;

sJogo jogo[MAX_JOGOS]; //global
sGlobals globals[MAX_JOGOS]; //global
HANDLE hMapFile; //global

int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {
   ...
   hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(sJogo)*MAX_JOGOS, szName);
   //create map for all games
   ....
}

//called when new game is created
void createView(int index){
   //create view for 1 game and store pointer
   //### need to apply offset here ###
   globals.pS[index] = (sJogo * )MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(sJogo);      
}

//called by thread on event set
void CopyJogo(int index){
  //use stored pointer to update jogo
  CopyMemory((PVOID)globals[index].pS, &jogo[index], sizeof(sJogo));
}
```

Client:

```
HANDLE hMapFile; //global
sJogo * pS; //global

int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {
    ...
    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, szName);
    pS =  (sJogo *)MapViewOfFile(cdata.hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(sJogo));
    //### need respective offset here ###
}
```

I have tried creating a view of "sizeof(sJogo)*MAX_JOGOS" and then incrementing the pointer+=sizeof(sJogo) * index; but didn't manage to succeed, so now I turn to you, can you help me learn to use the offset?

I have searched quite persistently and found a good example here on stackoverflow but it's C++ and I couldn't adapt it.

The high-order DWORD offset would be sizeof(sJogo) correct?
But I don't know what granularity is or how to apply it to the low-order DWORD...

Can you help me? 
Thank you.

---

EDIT:

The code below is returning when i = 1 (NULL), what am I doing wrong?

```
int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]) {
....
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(sJogo)*MAX_JOGOS, szName);
if (hMapFile == NULL)
{...}

DWORD offset = 0;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_JOGOS; i++) {
    if (MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, offset, sizeof(sJogo)) == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Erro MapViewOfFile I: %d\n"), i);
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return;
    }
    offset += sizeof(sJogo);
}
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

Solved the problem above, found the solution here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I wasn't taking into account the allocation granularity on the offset, which was causing MapViewOfFile to return NULL on the second attempt.

The link above shows a clear example on how to apply it to the offset.

Answer (score 1):

The example in MSDN should fit for you.
You can find it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx)

Basically in the `CreateFileMapping` you declare the amount of memory to share, in the `MapViewOfFile` you create a 'viewport' on the memory. It can have dimensions equal or a smaller than the quantity requested.

This memory can now be read or write.

On the client side you can open the mapping with `OpenFileMapping` then you should map the quantity of memory that you want access, the size of a single structure. Then you can iterate while `MapViewOfFile` returns a valid address to access all elements of the array:

```
sJogo *pS = NULL;
DWORD ofset = 0;
while((pS= (sJogo *)MapViewOfFile(cdata.hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, offset, sizeof(sJogo)))
{
    //Do something with the current element pointed by pS

    offset += sizeof(sJogo);
}
```

Here we start at offset zero in the mapped memory, than we increment offset by the size of our structure. This moves the mapping to the next element of the array of structures.

When we exceed the number of elements the file mapping will return NULL.

This is not the most efficient way to handle file mapping, you want consider to create a super structure holding the number of entries available and the entries coded as VLA (Variable Lenght Array) at the end of structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int nEntries;    //Holds the number of entries
    sJogo pS[];
} sGlobals;

sGlobals globals;
```

Comment: It's not that simple, as I expected, allocation granularity has to be taken into account when offsetting, applied it, it's working, thank you for the help.